# Can you recieve inaccurate data from chainlink?

Tags: chainlink

Can you receive inaccurate data from Chainlink blockchain oracles? What if the incentive to distort the data is more than the cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this is the same as:

```
Can you get inaccurate computation from Ethereum?
```

On a single Ethereum node, yes. A malicious, bought-off, or depreciated node could potentially say that `1+1=5`. This is why Ethereum is a decentralized network, and this is where Ethereum gets its security with computation.

Chainlink is the same methodology, but with data. A single Chainlink node pulling from a single source can return inaccurate data. However, a decentralized collective pulling from multiple sources won't.

Comment: This was a really good and simple explanation.